# Binding to a Dependency Property of UserControl

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF user control that has a DependencyProperty called IsMultiSelect.  I want to show hide a Button in the UserControl xaml.

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding IsMultiSelect, Converter=....}" />
```

This user control has a ViewModel assigned to the DataContext. 
The above syntax gives me a binding error due to the property not existing in the view model.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target the `UserControl` in different ways in the binding.

One solution would be to find it by setting a `RelativeSource` like this:

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding IsMultiSelect, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
    Converter=....}" />
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. That worked perfect. Thanks. Using ElementName also worked. <Button Content="Select All" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsMultiSelect, ElementName=MyControl, Converter=.. But yours is ideal. I went with this approach.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of binding to the property from xaml, the property changed handler for the dependency property should change the button's visibility.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMultiSelectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsMultiSelect", typeof(bool), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsMultiSelectPropertyChanged));

private static void OnIsMultiSelectPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as MyUserControl).OnIsMultiSelectPropertyChanged(e);
}

private void OnIsMultiSelectPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyButton.Visibility = (bool)e.NewValue ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}

public bool IsMultiSelect
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsMultiSelectProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsMultiSelectProperty, value); }
}
```

And you can put the converter logic inside OnIsMultiSelectPropertyChanged as well.